# FATAL EXCEPTION: main error Android development

Tags: java, android, exception

ERROR :

```
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gamecik/com.example.gamecik.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at com.example.gamecik.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-19 21:28:52.920: E/AndroidRuntime(17041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
```

When I use Admob code my application is error..if I delete Admob code my application is good..
PLEASE HELP ME...
Sorry that this question hasn't given much information, I just don't know what information to give to you (if that makes sense?) Please respond and tell me what information you would need and thank you for any and all of your help

HERE IS MY CODE:

MY ACTIVITY JAVA

```
package com.example.gamecik;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

         private MediaPlayer mp;
         private AdView adView;
         private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1715534499344773/3123443647";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      adView = new AdView(this);
      adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
      adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);

      layout.addView(adView);

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);


      // Add click listeners to all the ImageButtons

      View button1 = findViewById(R.id.sescalbuton);
      View button2 = findViewById(R.id.magnumsilah);
      View button3 = findViewById(R.id.Button03); 
      View button4 = findViewById(R.id.Button02);  
      button1.setOnClickListener(this);
      button2.setOnClickListener(this);
      button3.setOnClickListener(this);
      button4.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   // Required method if OnClickListener is implemented

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      // Find which ImageButton was pressed and take appropriate action

      switch(v.getId()){

         // The cow button
         case R.id.sescalbuton:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ak47);
         break;

         // The duck button
         case R.id.magnumsilah:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.magnum);
         break;

         // The sheep button                
         case R.id.Button03:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shotgun);
         break;

         // The uzi               
         case R.id.Button02:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
         break;

      } 

      mp.seekTo(0);
      mp.start();
   }
}
```

MY XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wood"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sescalbuton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shotgun"
        android:layout_below="@+id/magnumsilah"
        android:background="@drawable/ak47" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sescalbuton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sohtgun" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sescalbuton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sescalbuton"
        android:background="@drawable/guns" />

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1715534499344773/3123443647"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
         android:src="@drawable/supperweapon" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/magnumsilah"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:background="@drawable/magnum" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PLEASE HELP ME...WHAT IS PROBLEM ?

Comment: The error is clear: From the second line:  "AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout", and a little further down (line 15): "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout at com.example.gamecik.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)". So look at line #32 in your source, where you're typecasting `AdView` as a `LinearLayout`. You can't do that, as the error message clearly says. Read the actual words in the error message - they often actually have meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, casting is not your only issue. You're trying to add AdView to a LinearLayout that doesn't exist in your activities XML. But instead in your XML you've added an AdView and your initiating an AdView dynamically as well, which doesn't make any sense. Change your onCreate(..) code to the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
  adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);

  //.... rest of your onCreate() code
}
```

Comment: my error is different but this answer gave me a clue, which is an error due to an object that does not exist!

Answer (score 1):

Look for whatever R.id.adview is in your layout file. It's not a LinearLayout but you're trying to cast it as one. That's why it's crashing. Probably is an AdView?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be here,

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

where you are I believe trying to cast your AdView layout to a linear layout.

Change R.id.adView to the id of your LinearLayout. Post your layout xml too if this is not he case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project after changing the place. This worked for me!