# Android: Efficent Way of playing Sounds

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Here is my code, it's easier to show it to you and then explain:

```
public class Sound {
    public MediaPlayer audio;

    public Sound(Context context, int id) {
        audio = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), id);
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    Sound sound = new Sound(getContext(), R.raw.audio);

    public void method() {
        //plays only once here, so its not looping, which is good
        sound.audio.start();
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is have a class that defines a sound, and then allows me to play it, but when I load up my app on my phone, it crashes.

I just started working with sounds today so I don't know much about. I don't know why this doesn't work, and I planned on releasing my first app today.
Your help would be much appreciated!

Forgot to mention, the reason I'm doing this is so that my games sound doesn't crash due to creating many MediaPlayers.

Comment: Can you post an error you're getting?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Well, I got this in my log cat: "08-28 20:04:02.147: E/Trace(751): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"

Comment: @ChristianWaldmann that's not the error you're looking for (what you've posted is also an unrelated error from some other app if I'm not mistaken). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890899/fatal-exception-main-error-android-development is an example of an error that causes an app to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short sound samples it is better to use *android.media.SoundPool*.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.*;
```

anywhere in your Activity

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int soundId = soundPool.load(theContext, R.raw.audio, 1);
int streamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int streamId = soundPool.play(soundId, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```